# Split a Pandas DataFrame column based on a pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame which looks something like this

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({"Title":['t1','t2','t3'],
               "Description":['[rank:102] [status: Confirmed] [City: xyz] [Country:C1]',
                              '[rank:93] [status: Rejected] [City: abc] [Country:C2]',
                              '[rank: ] [status: Confirmed] [City: ] [Country: ]']})
```

As you can see, the important data which is needed for analysis is in the second column in a pattern which I want to separate.
What is the best way to separate 'rank','status','city' and 'country into different columns themselves.
Also, sometimes the data will will be absent in the description column for a few rows (record 3 for example)

As my final output, I would want my dataset to contain five columns

1. Title
2. Rank
3. Status
4. City
5. Country

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex with [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to extract the key/value pairs as two columns, then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to set the first column as column names, and finally [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to the original:

```
(d1
 .drop('Description', axis=1)
 .join(
  d1['Description']
  .str.extractall('([^][]+):([^][]+)')
  .droplevel(1) # get rid of extra "match" level to aggregate the rows into 1
  .pivot(columns=0, values=1)
 )
)
```

output:

```
  Title  City Country rank      status
0    t1   xyz      C1  102   Confirmed
1    t2   abc      C2   93    Rejected
2    t3                      Confirmed
```